# Joining Results of Stored Procedure with Temporary Table

Tags: sql-server, join, temp-tables

I have two tables that I have joined together. I'd like to join the result of the joined table with the results of a stored procedure that has two variables.

I'm not sure whether or not I should create two temporary tables or another function, so I'm a little lost on where I should even start and what the easiest method would be.

Below is my first join.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Users a WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN Company b ON a.email = b.email
```

Below is my stored procedure, all it does is split one column into more rows. Split is another function. I would like to use an inner join.

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM [dbo].[Menu] a
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(SalesPersons, ',') b
WHERE ID = @ID AND Date = @Date
```

Comment: Please provide stored procedure and logic also how you want to join.

Comment: Just edited! @SurajKumar

Comment: You should move that stored procedure code into a table valued function instead. Then you can `CROSS APPLY` it into your query

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! :) @MartinSmith

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith, I'm trying to do this but I'm pretty new at this stuff. How would you do this?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I managed it! Thanks anyways. :) @MartinSmith

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this, assuming that the output from the stored procedure is deterministic would be to populate the output of the stored procedure into a temp table and then join to it.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
   COL1 INT NOT NULL,
   COL2 INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #tmp
Exec sproc_YourSproc 'Params'


SELECT *
FROM dbo.Users u
INNER JOIN dbo.Company c ON u.email = c.email 
INNER JOIN #tmp t ON t.ID = c.ID
```

That being said, as Martin Smith said above, you probably want to move that logic into the stored procedure if possible.

Also, please don't use (NOLOCK) it doesn't really help the way most people think that it does, and it can cause some really nasty results. (Double reading rows, ghost records, ect)

If you need to be able to perform reads without causing read/write contention, I would investigate using more [optimistic isolation levels](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/), find ways to optimize the read performance to reduce possible congestion, or find indexing strategies that would [make it possible to satisfy reads](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) without locking the table itself.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance and feedback! I'll definitely try this out. :)